# Set default opportunity record type for a profile?

Tags: opportunity, profile, record-type, customization

Can some one tell me how to set a default record type for a custom profile? It should be very easy, however, I am not able to do that in our production org. I opened up the profile and went into Object Settings and I found that Opportunity object is not listed there. I went under the Customize ==> Opportunities ==> Record Types and Customize ==> Opportunities ==> Sales Process and I could not find a way to set a default record type for a profile.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Check the license type of the profile. If it is Salesforce, You can see it but if it is Salesforce Platform User, You can't.

[image]

Comment: I am using Salesforce license only and I am a System Administrator.

Comment: I found the issue. The profile belongs to the community license which does not have visibility to Opportunity object.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it has served it's purpose.